# How to count results when using inner joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a simple query below, which basically filters savings account for each branch.

```
SELECT Account.bID as Branch,branch.bAddress.street as Street, branch.bAddress.city as City, branch.bAddress.postcode as Postcode, Account.accType as Type
FROM Account
INNER JOIN branch
ON Account.bID=branch.bID where accType='savings';
```

I'm trying to add a count, so instead of displaying a list, it was display the amount of savings account for each individual branch. Im not too sure where im meant to add the count for this particular query.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT branch.bid, branch.bAddress.street as Street, 
branch.bAddress.city as City, branch.bAddress.postcode as Postcode,   
count(account.*) as savings_count
FROM Account
INNER JOIN branch
ON Account.bID=branch.bID where accType='savings'
group by branch.bid, branch.bAddress.street, 
branch.bAddress.city, branch.bAddress.postcode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `count(*)` in the `select` and a `group by`:

```
SELECT a.bID as Branch, b.bAddress.street as Street, b.bAddress.city as City,
       b.bAddress.postcode, a.accType as Type, COUNT(*)
FROM Account a INNER JOIN
     branch b
     ON a.bID = b.bID
WHERE accType = 'savings'
GROUP BY a.bID, b.bAddress.street, b.bAddress.city, b.bAddress.postcode;
```

This has replaced the table names with aliases, so it is easier to read.  But, some columns such as `b.bAddress.street` are not valid SQL.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it alot easier to read, and makes more sense. Your input is very much appreciated!